# How to move a window from one Window Manager to another running WM?

Tags: x11, window-manager, window

I use `libreoffice` on my `X11-server` and then I want to continue to work on the same text in the same window from another place using `VNC`.
So, it would be nice if it is possible to detach a `X11-window` from one Window Manager and attach it to a different one (on a different DISPLAY running on a different X-server) which is already running.

I'm using the `awesome window-manager`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `screen` to do that with (virtual) terminal applications, and there is [xpra](http://xpra.org/) for X11.